# How to uninstall sfproc.exe silent app (Possibly from timedoctor)

Tags: security, uninstall, privacy, remote-control, virus-removal

I was asked by my employer to download and install an exe. They didn't gave me much detail. But from the onset it looked like time doctor. I work from a home pc and I thought the version I was given to install would be interactive. But after some search I found out that it is a silent version. I have no problem with time doctor running while I am working but since I work remote and this is a personal pc I don't want it running 24/7. So my question is how do I uninstall this sfproc.exe. Currently I can't kill it via task manager. It just turns itself back on. There is no entry in the uninstall programs area. There is no entry in startup or registry "current version/run" But it is on every time I log on and keeps running. I am concerned with my privacy.

Comment: Out of interest, if you use Process Explorer (Microsoft/Sysinternals), can you suspend the process?

Comment: It says 'Suspended' in CPU column. But doesn't allow me the delete the exe.

Comment: if it's suspended it's not doing anything so it may be a good compromise if you should have this software running at least some of the time.  You could automate the suspension at differnt times using the command line tool PsSuspend, also by Microsoft/Sysinternals.

Comment: The program location is C:/ProgramData/SF/sfproc/2.1.0.40
Two exe I have identified from this.
sfproc.exe
staffservice.exe

Comment: When I kill these program from task manager. They seem to be gone for few seconds before turning itself back on. There is no way I am keeping this. But looking for options before fresh os reinstall. Oh also I can't start in safe mode. The keyboard arrow doesn't work while in boot mode selection menu.

Comment: If you are trying to remove it, not sure what the company will say, then it might be worth running Auto Runs (again Microsoft/Sysinternals) that should show you all the auto start locations for this product.  I can only assume, that it either has a service, which monitors for the processes you mention and starts them up or possibly it has a driver which does the same.  In these "watchdog" scenarios one option is to suspend the processes so neither can monitor each other but removing all the startup locations and rebooting should do it.

Comment: Using Auto Runs I found staffservice.exe in the service registry. Turning it off then rebooting the programs are no longer visible on process list. However I am still getting access denied while trying to delete the files. Even trying to delete from elevated command prompt fails.

Comment: One more tool of MS/Sysitnernals is psexec.  You could try running: `psexec -s -i cmd`  This will lanch a command prompt running as local system, you could try using that prompt.  Note: Sometimes psexec will get picked up by security software and you might need to authorise it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to finally remove the SF folder using psexec. While I am still paranoid some remnants might still be lurking. Can you believe it. Why not have a simple uninstall option. If I had known I would have never agreed to this on my personal pc. Why doesn't time doctor have a simple uninstaller. I thought it is a reputable program.

Comment: It's more likley down to the method of deployment chosen by the company deploying it. Glad you feel a bit more comfortable about it.  This article might be worth a quick look to see if it applies: https://www.timedoctor.com/help/how-to-export-app-local-data-and-find-time-doctor-local-cache-files-windows You may want to clear that down as well

Comment: I didn't find any TimeDoctor folder like that in appdata/roaming. I wouldn't have problem with interactive version which allows you to choose when you start working and log off times. And manage data. However. I got something which essentially acts like a passive RAT. 
https://support2.timedoctor.com/en/articles/2419933-silent-vs-interactive-apps

Comment: I agree, If they expecting you to install it on a personal device it should be very upfront with what data is being submitted and in what time period it is active.  For a company device, that's slighly different.

Answer (score 0):

Use the original .msi installer. And on the contextual menu, click on Uninstall.